# SelectableText widget does not show toolbar on web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Selectable text not showing toolbar on web. I checked with below code and it is working on mobile devices. I also checked [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/44176). Is there any work around for this?

```
body: Container(
        color: Colors.green,
        child: Center(
          child: SelectableText(
            'This is my selectable text widget. Hope you like it',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.purple,
            ),
            showCursor: true,
            toolbarOptions: ToolbarOptions(copy: true, selectAll: true),
            onTap: () {},
          ),
        ),
      ),
```